# TensorFlow Net disable log information

Tags: c#, tensorflow

How can I disable tenserflow information output in the console
Tried changing Environment "TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL" to 3
After looking at the answers on the Internet, I found only Python

```
2022-10-20 22:31:27.972310: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x22ca2648990 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2022-10-20 22:31:27.972477: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

Answer (score 0):

We can disable debugging information by using TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL environment variable. It can be set before importing TensorFlow.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
import tensorflow as tf
```

Or manually set this environment variable before running Python script.

```
SET TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=1
python main.py
```

For more details please refer to this [document](https://lindevs.com/disable-tensorflow-2-debugging-information). Thank You.